# savetrees and \raggedright interact badly

Tags: horizontal-alignment, savetrees

MCVE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}
\raggedright
\begin{document}
rgeg wrg wrg rgw rwg rwhrwghwrg e qeg rg wrg wr grw rh gr gwrg wrg 
rg wgr ewt rw wrt rwt rw  ewt rtw t rqqqqqqqqqqqqqqwt w we tw et ewt
w t wet wet wqet w t r wr thueiyuey  w ui eiuwy iywe iuyiew iie i 
ewiu ewiye iyewiuy iuew iueyiuyewiiuey iq  q qiyieqy iqiuyiriuy r
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

On the other hand, if I comment `\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}` I have

[image]

Is it possible to use together `savetrees` and `\raggedright`?

Note1: texlive 2016 on Debian Sid
Note2: the screenshots were taken using little care and with two different programs, hence differences in scaling and quality
Note3: prompted by Steven's answer i tried placing `\raggedright` before `\usepackage{savetrees}` but the result is the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or instead load savetrees with the `paragraphs=normal` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[subtle,paragraphs=normal]{savetrees}


\begin{document}\raggedright

rgeg wrg wrg rgw rwg rwhrwghwrg e qeg rg wrg wr grw rh gr gwrg wrg 
rg wgr ewt rw wrt rwt rw  ewt rtw t rqqqqqqqqqqqqqqwt w we tw et ewt
w t wet wet wqet w t r wr thueiyuey  w ui eiuwy iywe iuyiew iie i 
ewiu ewiye iyewiuy iuew iueyiuyewiiuey iq  q qiyieqy iqiuyiriuy r


\end{document}
```

[image]

[*** EDIT ***]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[subtle,paragraphs=normal]{savetrees}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}\raggedright

rgeg wrg wrg rgw rwg rwhrwghwrg e qeg rg wrg wr grw rh gr gwrg wrg 
rg wgr ewt rw wrt rwt rw  ewt rtw t rqqqqqqqqqqqqqqwt w we tw et ewt
w t wet wet wqet w t r wr thueiyuey  w ui eiuwy iywe iuyiew iie i 
ewiu ewiye iyewiuy iuew iueyiuyewiiuey iq  q qiyieqy iqiuyiriuy r

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The demo picture shows a right aligned text.  Look at the first line, "ewt" was squeezed in and the spacing in the first two lines seems a little bit different.

Comment: But it isn't right-aligned.  I'll add a `\lipsum` to the example to demonstrate.

Comment: I was confused, too.  It looked right-aligned, but you are right...it is not.

Comment: Both answers, incidentally, appear to use the same amount of paper: 16 lines into page 2 for the lipsum version of my example.

Comment: `savetrees` uses `microtype` to modify a little bit interword spacing so that lines that are _almost_ aligned are eventually right aligned, this is apparent from the first line where, adjusting the interword spacing, an extra word was forced in... If one turns off (`tracking=normal`) the fiddling with `microtype` they will find exactly the same line breaks that are obtained w/o `savetrees` (figure 2 of my OP).  So it seems that with your answer most lines are ragged, and a few are aligned thanks to `microtype` intervention... A good answer, possibly acceptable, let's wait a little. Thank you.

Comment: One year, 3 months and two weeks...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps load the `ragged2e` package (before `savetrees`) and use `\RaggedRight` instead of `\raggedright`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedRight
\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}
\begin{document}
rgeg wrg wrg rgw rwg rwhrwghwrg e qeg rg wrg wr grw rh gr gwrg wrg 
rg wgr ewt rw wrt rwt rw  ewt rtw t rqqqqqqqqqqqqqqwt w we tw et ewt
w t wet wet wqet w t r wr thueiyuey  w ui eiuwy iywe iuyiew iie i 
ewiu ewiye iyewiuy iuew iueyiuyewiiuey iq  q qiyieqy iqiuyiriuy r
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly an acceptable answer but for sure a useful one! Thank you

Comment: Looks good to me: why isn't it acceptable?

Comment: @JPi Useful because it solves my problem, not acceptable because it doesn't answer _specifically_ my question.

Comment: I guess the answer is `no` unless you set `paragraphs=normal`.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You get the same with the standard setting: mixing `\looseness=-1` with `\raggedright` is a very bad idea. And `savetrees` tries doing `\looseness=-1` for every paragraph, which is another bad idea.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\raggedright

rgeg wrg wrg rgw rwg rwhrwghwrg e qeg rg wrg wr grw rh gr gwrg wrg 
rg wgr ewt rw wrt rwt rw  ewt rtw t rqqqqqqqqqqqqqqwt w we tw et ewt
w t wet wet wqet w t r wr thueiyuey  w ui eiuwy iywe iuyiew iie i 
ewiu ewiye iyewiuy iuew iueyiuyewiiuey iq  q qiyieqy iqiuyiriuy r

\looseness=-1
rgeg wrg wrg rgw rwg rwhrwghwrg e qeg rg wrg wr grw rh gr gwrg wrg 
rg wgr ewt rw wrt rwt rw  ewt rtw t rqqqqqqqqqqqqqqwt w we tw et ewt
w t wet wet wqet w t r wr thueiyuey  w ui eiuwy iywe iuyiew iie i 
ewiu ewiye iyewiuy iuew iueyiuyewiiuey iq  q qiyieqy iqiuyiriuy r

\end{document}
```

[image]

I propose a different way for trying to minimize the number of lines in paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to show \raggedright is respected

% fix the silly thing savetrees does
\let\everypar\markeverypar
% use a high value for \linepenalty instead
\AtBeginDocument{\linepenalty=2000 }

\raggedright

\begin{document}

rgeg wrg wrg rgw rwg rwhrwghwrg e qeg rg wrg wr grw rh gr gwrg wrg 
rg wgr ewt rw wrt rwt rw  ewt rtw t rqqqqqqqqqqqqqqwt w we tw et ewt
w t wet wet wqet w t r wr thueiyuey  w ui eiuwy iywe iuyiew iie i 
ewiu ewiye iyewiuy iuew iueyiuyewiiuey iq  q qiyieqy iqiuyiriuy r

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I remove the setting to `\linepenalty`, this is the result. As you can see, one line is saved.

[image]

Comment: Learned something, thanks.  Guess fixing the silly thing savetrees does is the same as loading it with paragraphs=normal.

Comment: @JPi Possibly, but the options are treated in a very contorted way and it's difficult to understand what does what.

Comment: Thank you for the example **without** `savetrees`, things are much more clear now.